# how to join three tables with some conditions

Tags: mysql, payment

how to select all users logged in from 2+ countries and has 2+ failed transactions via (visa , mastercard , stripe)

tables structure

```
user
----------------------------------------
id  email           balance             
----------------------------------------
1   mail@app.com    $55
2   mail2@app.com   $50
3   mail3@app.com   $15

transaction 
----------------------------------------
id    uid   provider  amount   status  
----------------------------------------
1     1     visa      $55      1        // success
2     2     mpgs      $50      1
2     2     mpgs      $70      0        // new
3     2     paypal    $50      4        // failed
4     3     aex       $15      1
5     3     stripe    $1000    4
6     3     2check    $10      2        // pending

device
----------------------------------------
id  uid    ip            country   code 
----------------------------------------
1   1      242.235.23.5  USA       US
2   2      24.235.3.55   BRAZIL    BR
3   2      42.235.23.50  UK        UK
4   3      242.35.23.77  UAE       UA
5   3      24.235.23.34  MOROCCO   MA
```

Comment: i think your topic is contradicting what you're actually asking.
Which technology are you using?

Comment: What is the expected result based on the example data?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward:

```
select user.id
from user
join transaction on transaction.uid=user.id and transaction.status=4 and transaction.provider in ('visa','mastercard','stripe')
join device on device.uid=user.id
group by user.id
having count(distinct transaction.id) > 1 and count(distinct device.code) > 1
```

It might be more efficient to select users in more than one country in a subquery and join transactions to that subquery; you'd have to try with your actual data.